# Go Back to Previous Page

Tags: php, javascript

I am using a form to "Rate" a page. This form "posts" data to a php script elsewhere. I simply want to display a link after the form is processed which will bring the user back to previous page. Can I do this using javascript in my php script?

GF

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can use a link to invoke `history.go(-1)` in Javascript, which is essentially equivalent to clicking the Back button. Ideally, however, it'd be better to just create a link back to the URL from whence the user was posted to the form - that way the proper "flow" of history is preserved and the user doesn't wonder why they have something to click "Forward" to which is actually just submitting the form again.

Comment: How do I use a link to invoke that piece of javascript?

Comment: `<a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">link text here...</a>`

Comment: <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)">link text here...</a> will not work when the user has deleted history by clearing the cache...

Comment: @user1400915 then don't delete history or clear cache.

Comment: Is there a way to post the title of the previous page as well?

Answer (score 52):

Try this:

```
$previous = "javascript:history.go(-1)";
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])) {
    $previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
}
```

in html:

```
<a href="<?= $previous ?>">Back</a>
```

The JavaScript code is initialize as fallback for `HTTP_REFERER` variable sometimes not work.

Answer (score 36):

Depends what it is that you're trying to do it with.  You could use something like this:

```
echo "<a href=\"javascript:history.go(-1)\">GO BACK</a>";
```

That's the simplest option.  The other poster is right about having a proper flow of history but this is an example for you.

Just edited, orig version wasn't indented and looked like nothing.  ;)

Answer (score 26):

You specifically asked for JS solutions, but in the event that someone visits your form with JS disabled a PHP backup is always nice:

when the form loads grab the previous page address via something like `$previous = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];` and then set that as a `<input type="hidden" value="$previous" />` in your form. When you process your form with the script you can grab that value and stick it in the `header("Location:___")` or stick the address directly into a link to send them back where they came from

No JS, pretty simple, and you can structure it so that it's only handled if the client doesn't have JS enabled.

Comment: Isn't HTTP_REFERRER vulnerable to injection attacks?  It seems like it would be.  I like that it doesn't rely on JS, but looking for valid URL's seems like hassle.  The JS version looks more secure to me.

Answer (score 21):

Like this:

```
<?php

    if (isset($_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"])) {
        header("Location: " . $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"]);
    }

?>
```

Comment: This certainly works, but, alas, it's not really a Javascript solution :) (which is what the OP wanted)

Answer (score 15):

We can show a back button using html code in our pages which can take the browser window to the previous page. This page will have a button or a link and by clicking it browser will return to previous page. This can be done by using html or by using JavaScript in the client side.

Here is the code of this button

```
<INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Back" onClick="history.go(-1);">
```

**Using JavaScript**

We can use JavaScript to create a link to take us back to previous or history page. Here is the code to move back the browser using client side JavaScript.

```
<a href = "javascript:history.back()">Back to previous page</a>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think button `onclick="history.back();"` is one way to solve the problem. But it might not work in the following cases.

1. If the page gets refreshed or reloaded.
2. If the user opens the link in a new page.

To overcome these, the following code could be used if you know which page you have to return to. E.g. If you have a no of links on one page and the back button is to be used to return to that page.

```
<input type="button" onclick="document.location.href='filename';" value="Back" name="button" class="btn">
```

Answer (score 5):

... By looking at Facebook code  ... I found this
[image: Go Back to Previous Page]

Answer (score 4):

If your web-server correctly [redirects](http://www.thefutureoftheweb.com/blog/get-redirect-after-post) you to a new page after you made a post, the regular "back" button on the browser will work. Or the "history.go(-1)" in javascript. This will produce a filled out form.

However, if the server just returns new content without redirecting - then history.go(-1) is not going to help you. At that point you have lost your form.

If you just want to simply go back to the previous url - just link to it with an **A HREF** tag. That will show you an empty form.

Comment: PHP can generate redirects regardless of the web server.

Comment: True, but PHP runs ON the server. I am talking about client-server, not which software runs on the server.

Answer (score 4):

We can navigate to the previous page by using any of the below.

```
window.location.href="give url you want to go";
```

or

```
window.history.back();
```

or

```
window.history.go(-1);
```

or

```
window.history.back(-1);
```

Answer (score 2):

history.go(-1) this is a possible solution to the problem but it does not work in **incognito mode** as history is not maintained by the browser in this mode.