# Codeigniter Controller return to previous page after login

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing a login file and I want to go back to the previous page and not the homepage after I successfully login.

```
public function LoginUser(){
  if($checkEmail  == 1){
     header('refresh: 0 ; /')
  }
}
```

Comment: look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/2548580/6309457

Answer (score 0):

I recommended you store the previous page in a $_SESSION or temporary variable where you save your previous page because not all navigators can handle `history.go(-1)` and like this you can guarantee the user will redirect to the right page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. After successful login redirect to the desired page.

```
public function LoginUser(){
  if($checkEmail  == 1){
     redirect('/provide your controller name/');    
  }
}
```